# Compiling code directly into MSIL

Tags: jit, cil

Is there a way to complie code directly into Native Code instead of MSIL so that we can bypass JIT while executing the code on machine. If its possible. Please let me know the technique also.

Thanks

Comment: You mean "compile code directly into native code"? You can use ngen.exe to create native images of your .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compiling MSIL to Native Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(VS.71).aspx)  [Ngen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx)

> SUMMARY:
>
> The runtime supplies another mode of
>   compilation called install-time code
>   generation. The install-time code
>   generation mode converts MSIL to
>   native code just as the regular JIT
>   compiler does, but it converts larger
>   units of code at a time, storing the
>   resulting native code for use when the
>   assembly is subsequently loaded and
>   run. When using install-time code
>   generation, the entire assembly that
>   is being installed is converted into
>   native code, taking into account what
>   is known about other assemblies that
>   are already installed.

Take look at - [How to compile a .NET application to native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702/is-there-some-way-to-compile-a-net-application-to-native-code)

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET languages I'm familiar with, the source *is* compiled directly to `MSIL`.  What the `JIT` does is subsequently compile the `IL` code to native code.