# Compiling C# to Native?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, native

I think I'm somewhat confused about compiling .NET byte-code to native code, or maybe I'm confused about the end result.  So please bear with me as I try to sort through what I think I understand so you can help me figure out what I'm missing.

**What I'd like to do is compile my application written in C# down to regular native code** like I'd get if I had written it in C.  My reasoning has nothing to do with performance, but rather with some degree of protection.  I understand that my end-goal is not impossible (or even really that difficult) to circumvent, but I just feel like reversing x86 assembly is more difficult than reversing what Reflector gives me.

Right now if I throw my C# application into Reflector, I basically get my source-code back.  Typically when I throw my unmanaged C/C++ applications into IDAPro and use the HexRays decompiler, I don't quite get the same degree of decompilation back and I have to resort to wading through x86 disassembly to understand the logic flow.  It's my understanding that such great decompilation comes from Reflector due to the application being in MSIL instead of the more terse native code that HexRays tries to decompile.

I have no concerns about the client machine still needing the .NET runtimes, I'm not trying to circumvent any of that.  I would like to run normal software obfuscation programs like `upx` on my program, and doing it as a .NET binary fails.

It was my understanding from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702/is-there-some-way-to-compile-a-net-application-to-native-code) related question that `ngen` does what I want. I've tried using `ngen`.  But after copying the output file from the `C:\Windows\assemblies\...\applicationName.ni.exe` directory to somewhere I can double-click, and trying to run it produces an error about it not being "a valid Win32 application".  Further, when I toss the `applicationName.ni.exe` into Reflector, I get the same output as I did from just the `applicationName.exe`.  Since `applicationName.ni.exe` is supposed to be native code, I expected Reflector to error out, but it didn't.  If this the way I'm supposed to do this, why did Reflector still give me such a great decompilation?

So, just to summarize my main question again: How can I compile my .NET program into a native binary that Reflector won't so easily decompile?  Or what's some best practices for protecting a product written in a .NET language from newbie reverse-engineers?

If I need a different tool, I'd prefer something free and not something like [Codewall](http://www.codewall.net).

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I understand that what I'm looking for might limit some of the features of the language like Reflection, but I think I'm fine with that.  None of my code does any explicit `Assembly.Load` calls or anything of the sort.  But couldn't those just be replaced with `GetProcAddress/LoadLibrary` calls anyway?

Comment: On the code protectors/obstufactors most of them are commercial and moderately expensive if your not a software development company however even the top tier commercial ones can have tons of problems with your code actually working right after it does it's thing.

Comment: I need a similar functionality, also for security reasons.  My C# application needs to decrypt a config file that is distributed separately to each user (each file being different). The problem of course is that the code and algorithm for the decryption need to be in the C#, which is a risk if it can be recreated so easily.  I'm stumped for an alternative solution to this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I just **validated** **.Net Native** on **VS2015** & **Windows 8.1** (when configured correctly, examine .proj to validate) and building for a particular architecture (may be overkill, haven't validated), will produce a native file which will give you the "**harder to reverse engineer**" code you are looking for which for me was unabled to read **.dll** via **DotPeek**(free .Net decompiler from JetBrains).

Comment: Great!  Six years later and my dreams have finally come true. ;)

Comment: Note that this is for Windows 10 Universal apps, not WPF or WinForms. I.e., Windows 8.1 and above.

Comment: @EricEskildsen, so you can't compile to native for WPF/WinForms?

Comment: @jj_ With .NET Native? Not that I know of. That said, there may be other ways to compile WPF/WinForms to native today -- I haven't checked that space in a while.

Comment: @EricEskildsen Yeah, Delphi is one (and its correspondent open source project Lazarus).

Answer (score 33):

That's not how ngen.exe works.  It merely runs the JIT compiler up front to generate the .ni.exe or .ni.dll module.  That binary file does not contain metadata, only the machine code generated from the IL for the method bodies.  The CLR still must find the original assembly.  Only then can it determine that there is an ngen-ed image available so that it can use the machine code from it rather than generate it from the assembly's IL.

Ngen.exe speeds up the warm startup time of your app, that's all.

My usual advice to anybody that might be interested in disassembling my assemblies is to point them to sourceforge.net.  It has terabytes of source code, written and maintained by programmers that are usually better than me.  Sometimes even with good comments.  If your obfuscator doesn't work well then shop around for a better one.  There are many.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the explanation I was looking for with regard to what `ngen` is doing.  Do you have any suggestions on a good, free, obfuscator?

Comment: I only know good and free disassemblers.  A disassembler has to be free, asking money for it defeats the purpose of using one.  Good obfuscators cost money.  Visual Studio comes with one, Dotfuscator.  I never heard of a company that sells a product based on cracked source code that was protected by Dotfuscator.  That suggests it works well.

Answer (score 19):

Yesterday, at [Build 2014](http://www.buildwindows.com/), Microsoft announced [.NET Native](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn629511).  According to the [FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/dn642499.aspx), "... Initially, we are focusing on Windows Store apps with .NET Native. In the longer term we will continue to improve native compilation for all .NET applications."

Comment: But how can it be used in VS2013? I don't have VS2015 license so I want to use .Net Native in VS2013

Comment: @EldarZeynalov Maybe you should look at VS2015 Community Edition?

Answer (score 16):

If you want to protect your code, an obfuscator is the typical approach.  [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview) has been in an arms race with reflector for a while and we use it on our products.  In practice, however, a skilled human can easily read obfuscated code.

Compiling to native code defeats the purpose of having a managed language.  The main benefit is to allow the target runtime to JIT the IL into something that is optimally palatable for the target CPU.  If you want otherwise, you would use something like the [ahead-of-time option in mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime).

Comment: Doesn't Dotfuscator just obfuscate variable names so that it's more difficult to read?  And I get that I won't be receiving the run-time optimizations, and I'm OK with that.  My main purpose in using C# was the ease and beauty of the language's syntax and libraries, the nifty optimizations came second.

Comment: "Compiling to native code defeats the purpose of having a managed language" --This is not true.

Comment: One feature of managed .NET languages is, that they can be **verifiably safe**. Compiling verifiably safe IL to native code doesn't lose this specific feature. Also, what you describe as the *"main benefit"* does not even exist in reality (not even 5 years after you initially wrote this answer): While possible in theory, .NET's JIT compiler is extremely conservative, and the only noteworthy optimization that has happened since its inception is improved code **throughput**. No work has been done on optimizing the emitted native code.

Comment: Maybe then having a managed language defeats the purpose of having machine code after all, namely speed and power - the computer itself's raison d'être

Answer (score 10):

Other answers mention Microsoft's `.NET` Native compiler but do not tell you how to do that.

[Here](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/tree/master/samples/HelloWorld) is a tutorial using `CoreRT` on how to compile your `C#` project to native code.

Note:
I also had to comment out the following line for everything to work:

```
<!-- <add key="helloworld" value="https://api.helloworld.org/v3/index.json" /> -->
```

The output is a roughly `4MB` sized executable:

[image]

Indeed, the code is no longer readable with `.NET` decompilers and [`IDA Pro`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida) (a native code disassembler) recognizes it as native code.

Answer (score 8):

Spoon (previously Xenocode) has [a product that might fit your needs](http://spoon.net/Studio/Features.aspx). We use it for a WPF based installer UI so we don't have to bootstrap .net in order to load the setup program itself.

Comment: This looks fantastic, it's just a little more expensive than I'd like since I'm just a lone developer and not doing this for a company.

Comment: Indeed the price can be a bit prohibitive. It works well though.
Not sure if there are any open source or other alternatives out there. Another downside is it results in very large executable but the environment virtualization is pretty slick.

Answer (score 7):

NGEN adds native code, but it does not remove the MSIL. Therefore, any tool operating on the MSIL can still work. You also need this for reflection, something that would be very hard for a true native compiler.

Comment: None of my code explicitly uses Reflection, and I'm OK without it.  Barring some limitations on the language itself, is this possible?

Comment: You know it, but the hypothetical C#-to-native compiler can't really assume it.

Answer (score 6):

This is finally possible using Microsoft's .NET Native compiler

> It automatically compiles the release version of apps that are written in managed code (C# or Visual Basic) and that target the .NET Framework and Windows 10 to native code.

..

> •Your apps will provide the superior performance of native code.
>
> •You can continue to program in C# or Visual Basic.
>
> •You can continue to take advantage of the resources provided by the .NET Framework, including its class library, automatic memory management and garbage collection, and exception handling.
>
> For users of your apps, .NET Native offers these advantages:
>
> •Fast execution times
>
> •Consistently speedy startup times
>
> •Low deployment and update costs
>
> •Optimized app memory usage
>
> But .NET Native involves more than a compilation to native code. It transforms the way that .NET Framework apps are built and executed. In particular:
>
> •During precompilation, required portions of the .NET Framework are statically linked into your app. This allows the app to run with app-local libraries of the .NET Framework, and the compiler to perform global analysis to deliver performance wins. As a result, apps launch consistently faster even after .NET Framework updates.
>
> •The .NET Native runtime is optimized for static precompilation and thus is able to offer superior performance. At the same time, it retains the core reflection features that developers find so productive.
>
> •.NET Native uses the same back end as the C++ compiler, which is optimized for static precompilation scenarios.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397(v=vs.110).aspx

This is only available with VS.NET 2015.

Answer (score 5):

this is a free obfuscator, which is quiet good:
[eazfuscator](http://www.foss.kharkov.ua/g1/projects/eazfuscator/dotnet/Default.aspx)

Comment: Free for 30 days of use.*

Answer (score 3):

I might step back and ask why you are looking for this type of protection.  I'm not trying to argue that you don't need the protection, but I think it is worth understanding the motivation.

For instance, if you want protection because you have an algorithm in your system where it would be devastating to security if someone reverse-engineered it, then you might need to consider a different approach.  It means there is a flaw in the algorithm and no amount of obfuscation or native compiling will help you there.

If is a matter of IP, then I think obfuscation is probably your best approach here.  It is kind of like putting a lock on your door.  Someone can break the lock and get in, but they are intentionally doing it as opposed to just walking in the door.

Comment: Oh no, my algorithms aren't doing anything fancy.  It's somewhere in between academic curiosity and IP concerns.  I think a decent (but free) obfuscator would probably suit me fine for my IP concerns, but I do have a custom code packer that I've written previously that I would like to use on my .NET applications as well.  Any suggestions for an obfuscator?

Answer (score 3):

This is possible using the IL2CPU compiler. IL2CPU is developed by the same people who make COSMOS (C# Open Source Managed Operating System) and is only available by downloading cosmos. IL2CPU produces ASM files which can be compiled through Nasm (some other assemblers may work but it is best to use nasm). the only problem with IL2CPU is that it is built in to the Cosmos Project and it is quite difficult to get it to run on its own.

Comment: This looks like work based on IL2C at https://csnative.codeplex.com/ (that link might go away soon with the codeplex shutdown)