# Is there any way to bundle the .NET 4.5.1 framework with my desktop application?

Tags: .net

It's a .NET desktop application for Windows.

Is there any way to bundle the required framework files with the application so that users don't need to install it?

Currently, the application itself requires no installation and runs out of a share drive. I would like to somehow bundle the required framework files in that public folder so that users could run the application without installing the framework.

Comment: See this on MSDN: [Deploying the .NET Framework and Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbb4k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) and this [Installing the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek(v=vs.110).aspx#choices)

Comment: I can't deploy it formally due to computing restrictions the end users face, was hoping to bundle it to avoid this.

Comment: IMO That's not possible.. OS reads the PE header information from exe and load the application into memory using respective run time which in your case is .Net framework runtime. If the run time is not installed well.. you know what would the result be.

Comment: This may be instructive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453770/bundle-net-dlls-to-run-application-in-net-less-machine

Comment: you might want to use 4.5.2 since 4.5.1 is  not supported after january 12 2016

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a network share and you want your users to always have the latest version you should use Clickonce Deploy in online-only mode which will allow you to define prerequisites for running the software and it will install them if necessary.

> A ClickOnce application is any Windows Presentation Foundation (.xbap), Windows Forms (.exe), console application (.exe), or Office solution (.dll) published using ClickOnce technology. You can publish a ClickOnce application in three different ways: from a Web page, from a network file share, or from media such as a CD-ROM. A ClickOnce application can be installed on an end user's computer and run locally even when the computer is offline, or it can be run in an online-only mode without permanently installing anything on the end user's computer

For more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx