# Portable Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, portable-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some way to compile a .NET application to native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45702/is-there-some-way-to-compile-a-net-application-to-native-code)
>   [Running .net based application without .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework)

I wanna make C# windows form application that does not require to install .NET Frameworks ( i called it portable program ), how can i achieve this ?

I apologize if my question duplicate with another questions. I can't find my problem solution here.

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: not to install .Net frameworks or not needed... i believe C# form is based on the .NET framework so i dont know is you can do anything without it

Comment: You'd have to develop a Win32 application using MFC.

Comment: check this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/16483ed3-7782-406d-ade4-13daa7e9afbb/

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: I wanna develop based on C# language.

Comment: @HosseinMobasher Well then you'll need to use .NET framework in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. c# is using the .Net framework to function.

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an installation and setup package which will include your application as well as the .NET framework.

The user will run your setup program and install what is required.